# Dropbox Sync Folder - Dual Boot - Win 7 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, dropbox

I have dual boot computer with windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. Is there anyway to use the same Dropbox sync folder.

I tried to point to the same folder in Ubuntu but Dropbox refused to use the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem was solved:

1- Allow ubuntu to rename the existing folder to "Dropbox (old)" and create a new one "Dropbox"

2- exit Dropbox.

3- delete "Dropbox" and rename "Dropbox (old)" to "Dropbox"

Answer (score 0):

Creat a ntfs(because ntfs files can access from both system) partition on your computer then create directory on that partition and configure it as your dropbox folder in both system.

Comment: I have tried to use the Windows Dropbox folder, which is already NTFS, but ubuntu is refusing to using that folder. And it's asking me to allow it to change the main folder to Dropbox (old) and create a new one called Dropbox.